# What was the darkness that killed me in zone 3 in EverSpace?

Tags: everspace

There were lots of enemy ships and I haven't been focusing on the tutorial robot voice which was saying something about being turned inside out, which apparently happened to me. But I didn't hear what it said and I didn't see anything around that could have caused this. There were frequent moments of screen getting darker and darker until it suddenly turned to death camera and I was out on the main screen. What happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screen getting darker is indicating that you're flying near a black hole.

You can see the screen getting darker as I fly around a black hole.

Comment: Riiight, there was this wind particle effect and darkness, and the controller starts vibrating, but I couldn't see the actual black hole. I guess it could be because I'm playing on lowest settings, that the developers haven't anticipated a texture for it in that case.

Comment: It's possible.  The blackhole itself is not a texture, but a distortion of the graphics around it.  Might need to confirm if that's the case, since invisible black holes are really bad lol.

Answer (score 1):

It was the black hole, as it turns out. I just couldn't see it with effects turned down. Here's how it looks on high vs low:

[image]

[image]